# Ping PC goes to wrong Domain

Tags: dns

Quite new to the whole DNS Setup. Work has just made me a Domain Admin and I am adding a SCCM server to the network. This isn't really the issue.

I added the server to the DNS. This PC is on a different domain to the DNS server. Computer that is the issue is called SCCM-TEST on SCCMNETWORK.local. However when I ping this server it comes up as SCCM-TEST.SBSNETWORK.local not SCCM-TEST.SCCMNETWORK.local.

Need some help and would love some.

Comment: Can you confirm you created the record in the SCCMNETWORK.LOCAL zone and not in the SBSNETWORK.local zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was because SCCMNETWORK.local was within it's own DMZ network. The DMZ network was controlled by a device that housed a proxy connection for SBSNETWORK back to the main office and the whole network and NICs were set to push SBSNETWORK. Turning this off and setting it per zone fixed it. Also had to set DNS for both SBSNETWORK and forward it to the SCCMNETWORK and actually map a host definition of the machine so that it went to the correct IP.